# PropertyChanged doesn't fires specific getter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, inotifypropertychanged

I have this code part that does this:

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectLevelEnabled");
NotifyPropertyChanged("Plate");
```

I was expecting that this would end up calling the getter of SelectLevelEnabled and Plate, but **it only calls the Plate getter**. I've tried **changing SelectLevelEnabled to another name** and it still doesn't call the getter.

My PropertyChanged implementation is the following and it always worked well:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

The SelectLevelEnabled property is:

```
public bool SelectLevelEnabled
{
    get
    {
        return SelectedStatus != null && SelectedStatus.Id == DB_Status_Types.Dentro;
    }
}
```

I've tried:

- **Switching into Release/Debug**
- **Adding a setter** to SelectLevelEnabled
- **Changing the NotifyPropertyChanged("Plate")** to other properties and **all seems to work**. The problem is with SelectLevelEnabled.

Comment: Is anything listening for this changes?

Comment: It was not... I noticed this issue and added as answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer, that I found when I was writing the question, is that the SelectLevelEnabled **must have been binded by the View**, so it subscribes to be called by the PropertyChanged and the getter is called.

Comment: That's correct. If there is no view binded, there is no reason to framework *notify to/from view* when data is changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you call a property change from a different thread (other than the main thread), it won't update. 
You can use Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() to tell the main thread to update properties.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { MyProperty = newValue; }, new object[] { }); // method parameters go in the object array initializer.
```